# Preenchendo select com latitude, longitude e cidade de acordo com o Json

Tags: jquery, json

Eu tenho um formulário com dois selects, um de Estado e outro de Cidade. Eu já consigo popular meu select de cidade de acordo com a escolha do estado. O problema é que na hora do retorno Json no option, os campos de data-latitude e data-longitude ficam repetidos com os mesmo valores.

**HTML**

```
    <form action="obrigado.php" method="post" class="form" id="location__form">
      <fieldset class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select name="location__uf" id="location__uf" class="form-control required state">
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select name="location__cidade" id="location__cidade" class="form-control required city">
            <option value="">Cidade</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Script**

```
$.getJSON('js/estados-cidades.json', function (data) {
  var items = [];
  var options = '<option value="">Escolha um estado</option>';
  $.each(data, function (key, val) {
    options += '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
  });
  $("#location__uf").html(options);

  $("#location__uf").change(function () {

    var options_cidades = '';
    var str = "";

    $("#location__uf option:selected").each(function () {
      str += $(this).text();
    });

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
      if (val.nome == str) {

        $.each(val.latitudes, function (key_lat, val_lat) {
          latitude = val_lat;
          console.log(latitude);
        });
        $.each(val.longitudes, function (key_lat, val_long) {
          longitude = val_long;
          console.log(longitude);
        });
        $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city) {
          options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '" data-lat="' + latitude + '" data-long="' + longitude + '">' + val_city + '</option>';             
        });
      }
    });
    $("#location__cidade").html(options_cidades);

  }).change();

});
```

**JSON**

```
[
 {
  "sigla": "PI",
  "nome": "Piauí",
  "cidades": [        
    "Teresina",
    "Parque Piauí",
    "Água Branca"
  ],
  "latitudes": [
    "Teresina-lat",
    "Parque Piauí-lat",  
    "Água Branca-lat"   
  ],
  "longitudes": [
    "Teresina-long",
    "Parque Piauí-long",
    "Água Branca-long"     
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remova os demais loops e deixe somente esse, da forma que você criou cada loop é executado por vez ou seja, por isso  está ficando so os ultimos valores.

```
$.each(val.cidades, function (key, value) {
    var val_city = val.cidades[key];
    var latitude = val.latitudes[key];
    var longitude = val.longitudes[key];
    options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '" data-lat="' + latitude + '" data-long="' + longitude + '">' + val_city + '</option>';             
);
```